# DOM Elements Events Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have the below code in my project. I'm getting all anchor elements under `.pagination` and iterating over them and adding an event to each of them.

I added the `alert` in to prove that the elements have in fact loaded into the page and they are of the correct type (`HTMLAnchorElement`), however when I click on them, nothing fires. I even changed the event to various other types such as `mousedown`, `select`, etc.

```js
$(function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a')].forEach(e => {
        alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(e)); // [object HTMLAnchorElement]
        e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            alert('Click!');
            if (!this.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
                // Prevents last collapsable from being closed
                ev.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is anyone able to tell me why my events aren't firing?

Comment: As blanknamefornow has said in their answer, the code works as it is. You've to check, that there's no overlaying transparent element on your links, or `pointer-events: none` set in CSS for the links. For more convenient debugging, use DevTools to debug (ex. `console.log`) instead of alerts. Also, are the collected `a` elements having `href` attribute? If that's the case, you might want to prevent the default action instead of preventing propagation?

Comment: @Teemu There is no overlaying transparent element. There are other events on the links from Bootstrap that fire without issue and there is CSS hover effects that also work. I have used this exact snippet in another project for the same purpose and it works without issue.

Comment: What ever it is, it can't be reproduced by the provided code, like said, it works as it is. You've to build a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Wrong selector possibly,

```
$(function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.pagination a')) {
        console.log("Well a single search came up fine");
    }
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a')].forEach(e => {
        console.log(e);

        alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(e)); // [object HTMLAnchorElement]
        e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            alert('Click!');
            if (!this.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
                // Prevents last collapsable from being closed
                ev.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

To maybe make sure; code runs fine on my end?

I tested this

```
    [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(e => {
        console.log(e);
        e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            alert('Click!');
            if (!this.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
                // Prevents last collapsable from being closed
                ev.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });
```

in console and it turned every link to what you desired. So possibly a bad reference or something out of the blue! :X

Comment: Also another guess, [object HTMLAnchorElement] looks odd for an output.

Comment: That output is expected, as the selector collects `a` elements.

Comment: I'll have to maybe say it's a selector issue by far, worked perfectly with just 'a'. :)

Comment: In Console you can always go to Elements, and right click any of them Copy > Copy Selector. For fast querySelector lingo.

Comment: Not using the wrong selector. As I stated in the question, the initial alert triggers fine. I have two anchors matching the selector and I get two alerts of `[object HTMLAnchorElement]` just fine. It's `e.addEventListener` that doesn't fire.